# Interrupting an unstoppable looping SQL Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, interrupt, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

I've got a a script created as a stored procedure. The script is an infinite loop without anything that could make it wait indefinitely.

```
WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
   --Irrelevant code: Multiple record reads and writes
   WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10:000' --wait for 10 seconds before continuing.
END
```

I created an SQL Server agent job that launches the procedure, but **when I start the SQL Job it is impossible to stop it** without restarting the SQL Server Agent or crashing the procedure. It doesn't respond to any stop requests.

The only solution I can see is modifying the `WHILE 1=1` to `WHILE [value from table]=1`, but that wouldn't be an elegant solution and would still make it impossible to stop the job using SQL Agent.

**What I'm wondering is:**

Is it possible to alter the procedure in a way to make it stoppable by the server agent, but without removing the loop (there are variables outside of loop and I would prefer not to transfer them to tables)?

Comment: what does error message look like,when sql agent crashes,also cant you trigger the job every 10 seconds on so,instead of using a single job to go on forever

Comment: There's no error message or crash, I meant to say I cannot stop the script without crashing it. It just doesn't stop and that's it. Also the reason I don't want to remove the loop basically run the job every 10 seconds (appart from the fact Jobs only allow schedules with minutes as lowest time lapse between then) is I've got variables which I would have to transfer to tables and change quite a huge chunk of script (and that's no the only script I need to do this with)

Comment: To stop it on command without killing the process requres a way to send in a flag. The simplest way to do this is with a "STOP RUNNING" table that uses the @@SPID as the only data element. To end the process running on @@SPID 123, insert the value 123 into the table. Your check inside your loop would be something like `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM StopRunning WHERE spid = @@SPID) BEGIN DELETE FROM StopRunning WHERE spid = @@SPID; BREAK; END`  You could choose to check this every N loops to minimize your load.